# how to fit image inside middle Table cell of table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display an image in the center of my bootstrap4 table cell but it is showing to the left of the cell and even overlapping the border.  I have tried adding inline styles to the table cell html markup i.e text-align: center; vertical-align:middle; as well as to the css for the image but to no avail. I tried wrapping in span and still same result.  Also, my image for (.row.NotCompleted) is not displaying at all but path is correct as it is in same folder as the one that is displaying (.row.Completed)

HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="">
                <th scope="col" colspan="4">Please review your biographical information and update any missing information:</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:50px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; white-space:nowrap;">
                   <span><img class="row @PreferredNameRowStatus" /></span>
                </td>
                <td>Preferred Name:</td>
                <td class="itemValue">@Model.PreferredName</td>
                <td>
                    <a id="PreferredNameLnk" href="#">Click Here to Update</a><br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row.Completed {
        background-image: url("/images/Completed.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        display: block;
    }

    .row.NotCompleted {
        content: url('/images/Notcomplete.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        /* display set to block element */
        display: block;
        /*width: 100%;  */
        height: 100%;
    }

td img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: imageoutsidetablecell]

Comment: Does this help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position? If not you may load the image to a child div or directly via img tag and then center that div or img (https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: Background-position helped but I found that the culprit was a display:flex; style being pulled from bootstrap. I added display:inline; to the css along with the background-position:Center; and it resolved my issue!

Comment: I solved this by using razor to dynamically link the image src to the image file.  (i.e <img class="row image" src="@InsertRazorVariableHere" />) this worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row.Completed {
        background-image: url("/images/Completed.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        display: block;
    }

    .row.NotCompleted {
        content: url('/images/Notcomplete.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        /* display set to block element */
        display: block;
        /*width: 100%;  */
        height: 100%;
    }

td img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="table-responsive container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="">
                <th scope="col" colspan="4">Please review your biographical information and update any missing information:</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:50px; text-align: -moz-center;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: -webkit-center;">
                   <span><img src='https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png' class="row @PreferredNameRowStatus" /></span>
                </td>
                <td>Preferred Name:</td>
                <td class="itemValue">@Model.PreferredName</td>
                <td>
                    <a id="PreferredNameLnk" href="#">Click Here to Update</a><br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
</table>
</div>
```